# URL / API schema best practice

Tags: rest, url

I constantly bump in this problem and don't know what is the best practice with this.
So, for example i want three endpoint of my angular app:

1. List all my patients page
2. Create a patient page
3. Detailed page of a patient

My brain suggest the following:

1. /patient
2. /patient/add
3. /patient/{id}

It seems off a bit beacause 2. and 3. could cause issues? Okay the id will never be 'add' especially if id is an integer.

Almost the same goes with API. But there we have POST, PUT etc.
So the example changes a bit like:

1. /api/measurement/dashboard -> aggregated info about all measurements all user (count, groups etc.)
2. /api/measurement/{user} -> aggregated info about measurements of a specific user
   (It doesn't matter i guess bit measurements contains data like HR, Weight etc.)

Is this common to create endpoints like that? Is it a good or good enoguht practice?

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view

```
GET /patient
PUT /patient
POST /patient
GET /patient/{id}
```

looks ok.

For the second part

```
GET /api/measurement
GET /api/measurement?user={userId}&group={groupId}
```

should work in your case if I understand the context correctly.